# Python 3 Rock, Paper, Scissors game NameError: name 'computer_choice_rock' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game for a programming class. This is where I got and then PowerShell spits out that error. I don't understand what is wrong (I am a beginning Python programmer). My programming teacher is not much help and prefers the "Figure it out" approach to learning. I am genuinely stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
import random

def rps():
    computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if computer_choice == 1:
        comuter_choice_rock()
    elif computer_choice == 2:
        comuter_choice_paper()
    else:
        comuter_choice_scissors()

def computer_choice_rock():
    user_choice = input("1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        print ("It's a Tie!")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("You Win! Paper covers Rock!")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("I Win and You Lose! Rock crushes Scissors!")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("Please type in 1, 2, or 3")
        computer_choice_rock()

def computer_choice_paper():
    user_choice = input("1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        print ("I Win and You Lose! Paper covers Rock!")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("It's a Tie!")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("You Win! Scissors cut Paper!")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("Please type in 1, 2, or 3")
        computer_choice_paper()

def computer_choice_paper():
    user_choice = input("1 for Rock, 2 for Paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == ("1"):
        print ("You Win! Rock crushes Scissors")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("I Win! Scissors cut Paper!")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("It's a Tie!")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("Please type in 1, 2, or 3")
        computer_choice_paper()

def try_again():
    choice = input("Would you like to play again? Y/N: ")
    if choice == "Y" or choice == "y" or choice == "Yes" or choice == "yes":
        rps()
    elif choice == "n" or choice == "N" or choice == "No" or choice == "no":
        print ("Thanks for Playing!")
        quit()
    else:
        print ("Please type Y or N")
        try_again()

rps()
```

Comment: Look closely, you have a spelling error: the function is called "com**p**uter_choice_rock" in its definition,  while in the call it's "co**mu**ter_choice_rock" (the "p" is missing).

Comment: Wow, couldn't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in you code

```
if computer_choice == 1:
    comuter_choice_rock()
elif computer_choice == 2:
    comuter_choice_paper()
else:
    comuter_choice_scissors()
```

Comuter

Comment: you are supposed to accept an answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified to an extreme degree. See the following example program. To replace either of the players with a NPC, set `player_1` or `player_2` with `random.choice(priority)`. If you want to, you could even have the computer play against itself.

```
priority = dict(rock='scissors', paper='rock', scissors='paper')

player_1 = input('Player 1? ')
player_2 = input('Player 2? ')

if player_1 not in priority or player_2 not in priority:
    print('This is not a valid object selection.')
elif player_1 == player_2:
    print('Tie.')
elif priority[player_1] == player_2:
    print('Player 1 wins.')
else:
    print('Player 2 wins.')
```

You could also adjust your game so people can play [RPSSL](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html) instead. The code is only slightly different but shows how to implement the slightly more complicated game. Computer play can be implemented in the same way as mentioned for the previous example.

```
priority = dict(scissors={'paper', 'lizard'},
                paper={'rock', 'spock'},
                rock={'lizard', 'scissors'},
                lizard={'spock', 'paper'},
                spock={'scissors', 'rock'})

player_1 = input('Player 1? ')
player_2 = input('Player 2? ')

if player_1 not in priority or player_2 not in priority:
    print('This is not a valid object selection.')
elif player_1 == player_2:
    print('Tie.')
elif player_2 in priority[player_1]:
    print('Player 1 wins.')
else:
    print('Player 2 wins.')
```